# How do I deal with an affectionate nipping cat

Tags: pets

My cat Simon is awesome and affectionate however when he doesn't get his way he will start nipping at my calves and ankles.  I don't want to scold him and yet I don't want to get bit either.  He isn't breaking the skin however I do feel it is important to deal with it.  My cat is declawed and well-taken care of.  He is taken to the vet for checkups and has an automatic feeder to ensure he is always fed.

Comment: Well, we *do* have our sister site: [Pets Stack Exchange](http://pets.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Can we migrate this question to petsSE?

Comment: @JustDoIt We don't generally prefer to migrate questions that do not have significant content. Migrations are typically used to preserve answers that would be a shame to lose. Migrating a question where the author may not have an account is problematic enough, but migrating also bypasses the in-question dupe check and it may not fit the rules of that site; not to mention the tags are almost certainly wrong, etc, etc. Migration is not a good choice in these cases. The user should simply re-ask the question in the context of *that* site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting something harmless but foul-tasting on your skin or clothes (e.g. soap or insect repellent) is effective.

Comment: Try vicks vapo-rub. It should repel your cat. I found out on Bondi Vet that it repels dogs as well.